# Finding the inverse function on a LTree

Tags: haskell

In a LTree defined as:

```
data LTree a = Leaf a | Fork (LTree a) (LTree a)
```

I creates a list with all the leafs and the respective level like this:

```
cross :: LTree a -> [(a,Int)]
cross (Leaf x) = [(x,0)]
cross (Fork e d) = map (\(x,n) -> (x,n+1)) (cross e ++ cross d)
```

Now I want to create the inverse function:

```
build :: [(a,Int)] -> LTree a
```

So that build (cross a) = a for every LTree a

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some hints.

First hint: write an auxiliary function which, given a level, "consumes" pairs from a list and builds a subtree for that level. It returns both the subtree and the rest of the list (the pairs which have not been consumed). This has type

```
aux :: Int -> [(a, Int)] -> (Tree a, [(a, Int)])
```

Examples:

```
aux 1 [('a', 2), ('b', 2)]
  -- a subtree at level 1 which has leaves at level 2
  = (Fork (Leaf 'a') (Leaf 'b'), [])
aux 0 [('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)]
  -- no leaf remains
  = (Fork (Fork (Leaf 'a') (Leaf 'b')) (Leaf 'c'), [])
aux 1 [('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)]
  -- a leaf remains
  = (Fork (Leaf 'a') (Leaf 'b'), [('c', 1)])
aux 2 [('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)]
  = (Leaf 'a', [('b', 2), ('c', 1)])
aux 0 [('a', 0)]
  = (Leaf 'a', [])
```

Second hint: to implement `aux`, start by comparing the level to the level in the first pair in the list.

After `aux` is implemented, it is easy to derive the `build` function from it. (How?)